# ComboBox and showing from datagrid

Tags: mysql, combobox, vb.net-2010

Can someone help me out. I have a combobox where the items are from my database. If I drop down the combobox and select an item, the datagridview must show the firstname,lastname etc. My data type at studentno is varchar, the int does not work too. The data will be get from two different table

2nd is how can I refresh the combobox? Because I need to close then reopen the program before the data that will be insert at combobox.

```
Private Sub ComboBox6_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox6.SelectedIndexChanged
    conn.Open()
    query = "select student.studentno,student.firstname,student.middlename,student.lastname,subject.subjcode,subject.subjdesc from student,subject where student.studentno = '" & ComboBox6.SelectedText & "' "
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    ds = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "ds_student,subject")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "ds_student,subject"

    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and then i came up  with this

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Folha de Obra com Tabela Clientes.accdb;Persist Security Info=True")

    Dim query As String

    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

    Dim ds As New DataSet

    conn.Open()

    query = ("select * from Obras where IdCliente = " & ComboBox1.ValueMember)

    cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, conn)

    da.SelectCommand = cmd

    da.Fill(ds, "NomeObra")

    ComboBox2.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

    ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "NomeObra"

    ComboBox2.ValueMember = "IdCliente"

    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

I hope it helps you